# Extract the 1st, 4th and 8th page from multiple pdfs

Tags: windows, pdf

I have 268 PDFs to go through and need to extract the 1st, 4th and 8th page of. so instead of having a pdf file of multiple pages, I need to somehow make them into files with the desire pages only. I'm hoping that there is a more efficient way than doing it manually and save some time by have a batch process to extract just the desire pages from the 268 pdfs and place it in a new pdf. Does anyone know any other programs or methods that this could be achieved?

I know that there is a form for extracting the first page and it involves some code writing but I'm not familiar with and I don't know how to code it that it will give me the 1st, 4th and 8th page only.

I'm operating on a windows computer.

Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on Windows, you could use PowerShell and PDFTk to achieve your goal with a single click

```
$pdftk = "C:\pdftk_server-2.02-win-setup\{app}\bin\pdftk.exe"
$input = "C:\originalPDFs"
$output = "C:\newPDFs"

Get-Childitem -path $input -filter *.pdf -recurse | foreach {            
    & $pdftk $_.Fullname cat 1 4 8 output $output\$_
    }
```

### Howto

1. Download [PDFTk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/). That's the command line version of the popular PDFTk software

   However, since its a commandline utility, we don't want to install it. Instead use [UniExtract Binary Archive](http://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract) to extract the downloaded file *pdftk_server-2.02-win-setup*
2. When done correctly, you get a new folder. Under `..\{App}\bin` are the two files we need:   `libiconv2.dll`  and `pdftk.exe`.
3. Create a new text file and paste in the above code. Change all three path variables according to your own needs. They are self explaining
4. Save it as `SomeName.ps1`, right-click it and select `Run with PowerShell` to execute the script

The important part is `& $pdftk $_.Fullname cat 1 4 8 output $output\$_` which reads as

- `& $pdftk` » Run PDFTk utility with some arguments following
- `$_.Fullname` » take the current PDF's full path as input file
- `cat 1 4 8` » catenates the 1st, 4th and 8th page from our input PDF to create a new PDF
- `output $output\$_` » file name for new PDF. It's the *output* folder plus the original PDF name

### References

- https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/ (Download PDFTk)
- https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/ (Full manual)
- https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/ (Examples)
- http://ss64.com/ps/ (List of PowerShell commands)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a option you would consider... If you have a adobe version that lets you make make pdfs then you can print those pages you require to the adobe virtual printer and make a new pdf of the pages you require.

Comment: Do you know what version of pdf do I need?

Comment: I meant what very of Adobe*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version adobe acrobat professional v10. Just thought of another option... you can use any 3rd party pdf creator that should be available for free download to achieve the same thing.